# JQuery Cleanup and auto select next div and nav item

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first of my questions is this; I have 5 images, that when clicked show a related div and hide the rest. This is how I have coded it and I just get the feeling that its a messy and verbose way of coding. Been new to jQuery I'm just asking for your advice. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);

$('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);

$("#nav-fragment-0").click(function() {
    $('#fragment-0').show();
    $('#fragment-1').hide();
    $('#fragment-2').hide();
    $('#fragment-3').hide();
    $('#fragment-4').hide();


    $('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);


    });
$("#nav-fragment-1").click(function() {
    $('#fragment-1').show();
    $('#fragment-0').hide();
    $('#fragment-2').hide();
    $('#fragment-3').hide();
    $('#fragment-4').hide();

    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);

    })
$("#nav-fragment-2").click(function() {
    $('#fragment-2').show();
    $('#fragment-0').hide();
    $('#fragment-1').hide();
    $('#fragment-3').hide();
    $('#fragment-4').hide();

    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);

    })
$("#nav-fragment-3").click(function() {
    $('#fragment-3').show();
    $('#fragment-0').hide();
    $('#fragment-1').hide();
    $('#fragment-2').hide();
    $('#fragment-4').hide();

    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 1);

    $('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);

    })
$("#nav-fragment-4").click(function() {
    $('#fragment-4').show();
    $('#fragment-0').hide();
    $('#fragment-1').hide();
    $('#fragment-2').hide();
    $('#fragment-3').hide();

    $('#nav-fragment-4').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('#nav-fragment-0').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-1').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-2').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $('#nav-fragment-3').fadeTo("slow", 0.33);

    })


});
```

Here is the UL containing the images for the navigation which is clicked

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a><img src="2013/08/16-150x112.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="57" id="nav-fragment-0" ></a></li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a><img src="2013/05/1-150x112.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="57" id="nav-fragment-1" ></a></li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a><img src="2013/06/P6172474-150x112.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="57" id="nav-fragment-2" ></a></li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a><img src="2011/12/Florence.out_-150x112.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="57" id="nav-fragment-3" ></a></li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected"><a><img src="2013/08/11-150x112.jpg" alt="" width="90" height="57" id="nav-fragment-4" ></a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the divs:

```
<div id="fragment-0" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
<div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
<div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
<div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide"></div>
```

The second question is, How do I get these to flick through each one after 10 seconds and then continuously loop through them?

Comment: Can you please share the part of html related to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should more or less work I think, you need to add a class to all the items (class="itemClass"):

```
for (i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    $("#nav-fragment-" + i).click(function() {
        $(".itemClass").hide().fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
        $("#fragment-" + i).show().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your html you could do something like this :

1. Use same class for all your nav-fragments : .nav-fragments
2. Bind all .nav-fragments to something like : http://jsfiddle.net/hxU4G/

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);

$(this).siblings(".nav-fragment").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the divs related to images and images themselves some class. Like:

```
<img src="#" class="someImg" />
<img src="#" class="someImg" />
<img src="#" class="someImg" />
<img src="#" class="someImg" />
<img src="#" class="someImg" />

<div class="relatedDiv"> ... </div>
<div class="relatedDiv"> ... </div>
<div class="relatedDiv"> ... </div>
<div class="relatedDiv"> ... </div>
<div class="relatedDiv"> ... </div>
```

now with jQuery check which one was clicked:

```
$(".someImg").click(function(){
    var eq = $(this).index() - 1; // because index() is one-based and eq() is zero-based

    $(".someImg").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $(".relatedDiv").hide().eq(eq).show();
})
```

As for the second part of your question you can use setInterval function (it would be easier if you set an additional class like "active" to determine which one of images is currently chosen)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest handling your active states with CSS, and just use jQuery to toggle those classes.

[Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/ACwLq)

**jQuery**

```
$('.nav-fragment').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav-fragment').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='nav-fragment active'></div>
<div class='nav-fragment'></div>
<div class='nav-fragment'></div>
<div class='nav-fragment'></div>
<div class='nav-fragment'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-fragment {
  background: crimson;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.33;
  width: 200px;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
     -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
          transition: opacity 1s;
}

.nav-fragment.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any class or div to your html, you can solve the problem like this

```
//initialize these arrays with all the nav-fragments and fragments ids
var navFragment = [$("#nav-fragment-0"), $("#nav-fragment-1"), $("#nav-fragment-2")];

var fragment = [$("#fragment-0"), $("#fragment-1"), $("fragment-2")];

//from here the problem is solved in general
var i,j;
for(i=0; i < navFragment.length;i++) {
   navFragment[i].click( (function(selected) {
     return function() {
       for(j=0; j < navFragment.length;j++) {
            if(j !== selected) {
                fragment[j].hide();
                navFragment[j].fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
            } else {
                fragment[j].show();
                navFragment[j].fadeTo("slow", 1);
            }
        }
     }
   })(i);    
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Arnaud's answer however in reference to your second part of the query, to loop through them you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    iterator = 1;

    $("a.nav-fragment").on("click", function (event) {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).siblings("a.nav-fragment").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    });

    // set interval for ever 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    setInterval(function () {
        $($("a.nav-fragment")[iterator - 1]).trigger('click');
        if ((iterator) == $("a.nav-fragment").length) {
            iterator = 1;
        } else {
            iterator++;
        }
    }, 1000)

});
```

full fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rp4ZJ/

Remember if you want to make it go every 10 seconds to add a 0 onto the milliseconds and also to initially trigger a click on the first one to begin with.
This will also carry on after someone clicked.  Carrying on from where the iterator is.  If you want to change the order you can manipulate the value of the iterator in the click listener.